# Geometry shape identification and vertex/side label association

Tags: image-recognition

I want like to be able to draw a shape outline e.g. (pen and paper) triangle, square, circle.. then label the vertices and sides And have ML identify the shape and the symbol associates with each vertex / side.

For example a triangle and I label it with the adjacent, opposite and hypotenuse. Or draw parallel and perpendicular lines and label angles and such.

I would prefer it make one myself rather than use a pre built one. However if you know of a simple pre built one then I will ould love to pick it apart.

Can you please share some guidance on how to solve the above problem, namely shape identification / vertex and side labelling.

Any language